# CakePHP 3.x: saving multiple records

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I've read [Converting Multiple Records](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#converting-multiple-records). Now I'm trying to save multiple photos at once from a form.

With:

```
debug($this->request->data);
```

I've this:

```
[
    (int) 1 => [
        'filename' => '25483_106728809362869_5795827_n.jpg',
        'description' => '',
        'album_id' => '2'
    ],
    (int) 3 => [
        'filename' => '44569_193398817463220_816845208_n.jpg',
        'description' => '',
        'album_id' => '1'
    ]
]
```

It seems ok.

Bake has created for me this action method:

```
public function add() {
        $photo = $this->Photos->newEntity();

        if($this->request->is('post')) {
            $photo = $this->Photos->patchEntity($photo, $this->request->data);

            if($this->Photos->save($photo)) {
                return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
            }
        }

        $this->set(compact('photo'));
    }
```

But the CakeBook doesn't explain well how to proceed. I sense I have to use `newEntities()` and `patchEntities()`, but I don't quite understand how to do.

For example: why the `newEntity()` method can accept NULL, while the method `newEntities()` necessarily wants an argument??
The `save()` method accepts only one entity at a time? So, I have to cycle saving for each entity?

Can I have a small example? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming your data is in the correct format, it should be as simple as this:

```
$photos = $this->Photos->newEntities($this->request->data());

foreach ($photos as $photo) {
    $this->Photos->save($photo);
}
```

`newEntity()` can accept a null because calling newEntity with no data creates a blank entity that you can add data to, in case you don't want to pass in request data. For example:

```
$photo = $this->Photos->newEntity();
$photo->description = 'Cool!';
$photo->filename = 'example.jpg';

$this->Photos->save($photo);
```

`newEntities()`, however, expects multiple data or at least an array of data if you want to make many entities.

Comment: Thanks @Isaac. But I noticed one thing. If I use `newEntities()`, I can do it only after the form has been sent (as you say).
Normally, however, with Bake the `newEntity()` creates a blank entity which is passed to the template and is used to create the form (in this case: `$this->Form->create($photo)`). How to do in this case?

Comment: Also, I don't think that the `save()` method can save multiple entities at once. In fact, doing some testing, I get this error:
`Error: Call to a member function errors() on array
File [...]/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/ORM/Table.php
Line: 1302 `

Comment: It seems to me that the solution is: 1) create an empty entity with `newEntity()`, which will be used by the form; 2) when the form was sent, recreate the entity using `newEntities()` and passing `$this->request->data`; 3) cycling every entity to `save()`

Comment: Just like it's shown in the cookbook. **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#changing-accessible-fields**, **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/saving-data.html#merging-request-data-into-entities** @MirkoPagliai

Answer (score 2):

**Using saveMany:**

In some occasions it would be even better using saveMany which don't need foreach loop anymore.

```
    $entities = $this->Photos->newEntities($this->request->data());
    if($this->Photos->saveMany($entities)) {
        // saved
    } else { 
        // error
    }
```